# Does successive application of $\sin$ function on some nonzero algebraic number ever yields a sequence of transcendental numbers?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

On the Wikipedia page about [Transcendental numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) there is a section about numbers that are proven to be transcendental and there you can read that transcendental numbers are *sin(a), cos(a) and tan(a), and their multiplicative inverses csc(a), sec(a) and cot(a), for any nonzero algebraic number a (by the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem)*.

Let $\sin_1(x)=\sin(x)$ and $\sin_2(x)=\sin(\sin(x))$, and, more generally, $\sin_n(x)=\sin_{n-1}(\sin(x))$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$.

> Is it true that there exists nonzero algebraic number $\alpha$ such that the set $\{\sin_n(\alpha): n\in \mathbb N\}$ contains only transcendental numbers?

Comment: After taking two sines I think the problem is already beyond modern technology.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Really? I did not expect that the problem would be so tricky.

Comment: Mainly because I do not want a concrete example of such a number, only the proof that there exists at least one.